# KeyError: code error before uploading data to df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

i’m getting error after run code even i check if df is not None before run the code, but error disappear after upload data

```
'''
def loadData():
    data =pd.DataFrame()
    uploadFile= st.file_uploader("Choose output.csv file")
    if uploadFile is not None:
       df = pd.read_csv(uploadFile)
       data = df
    return data

df = loadData() 

if df is not None:
   def mergePop():
       
          #appended pop list
          popList=[]
          for us in df['UserName'] :
              if us is not None:
                 if us[:2] == '02':
                  popList.append('Cairo')
              
                 
                 elif us[:2] == '03':
                  popList.append('Alx')
                  
                 else:
                  popList.append('NA')
                  
          popS= pd.Series(popList)      
          return popS
          
if df is not None:
   df['pop']=  pd.Series(mergePop())
   st.dataframe(df)

'''
```

KeyError: ‘UserName’

```
Traceback:

File "c:\anaconda3\envs\elbouhy-env\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)File "C:\Users\ramye\Desktop\test3.py", line 46, in <module>
    df['pop']=  pd.Series(mergePop())File "C:\Users\ramye\Desktop\test3.py", line 28, in mergePop
    for us in df['UserName'] :File "c:\anaconda3\envs\elbouhy-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)File "c:\anaconda3\envs\elbouhy-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
```

[image]

Comment: +add , how to prevent check df columns before load it

Answer (score 0):

Solved by add

- global df
- check columns by df.get()

  '''

  ```
        global df
        def loadData():
            data = pd.DataFrame()
            uploadFile= st.file_uploader("Choose output.csv file")
            if uploadFile is not None:    
                data =pd.read_csv(uploadFile)
            return data

        def mergePop():
                  #global df
                  popList=[]
                  if df.get('UserName') is not None:
                     for us in df['UserName'] :
                         if us is not None:
                            if us[:2] == '02':
                               popList.append('Cairo')
                            elif us[:2] == '03':
                                 popList.append('Alx')
                            else:
                                 popList.append('NA')
                  popS= pd.Series(popList)      
                  return popS


        df=loadData()
        df['pop']=  pd.Series(mergePop())
  ```

  '''